# Character Controller and Collisions в Unity

Tags: unity3d

В простой игре(раннер) мне надо отслеживать столкновения с конкретными препятствиями помеченными тэгом "enemy". Я использую в игре CharacterController и OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class mainPlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{   
    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        print(hit.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Но при столкновении с "enemy" лоб в лоб столкновение не отслеживается (отслеживаются только боковые столкновение. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

из документации:
[OnControllerColliderHit вызывается тогда, когда контроллер сталкивается с коллайдером, во время выполнения метода Move](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnControllerColliderHit.html)
Возможно, в Вашем случае, когда объект натыкается на игрока, игрок не перемещается.